Is this combination of Lukasiewicz proof systems complete?
I’ve been learning more about axiomatic systems, and somewhat recently came across the following axiomatization for Classical Propositional Calculus a la Lukasiewicz:
$(A \to B) \to (B \to C) \to A \to C$
$A \to \neg A \to B$
$(\neg A \to A) \to A$.
Along the way, I’ve learned that proving $(A \to (A \to B)) \to A \to B$ as a theorem is important for proving the Deduction Meta-theorem in the absence of the distribution of implication axiom. This made me wonder if the following combination of Lukasiewicz systems would result in a complete proof system over Modus Ponens:
$A \to B \to A$
$(A \to B) \to (B \to C) \to A \to C$
$(A \to (\neg B \to \neg A)) \to A \to B$

Is there an obvious tautology that can be given a counter-model over these axioms that I’m missing? I can’t tell if $(A \to B) \to \neg B \to \neg A$ is a theorem. If it is, then I can prove the system is complete. Thanks.

Every single obvious tautology is a counter-model to those, because there are no rules to transform those un-well-formed-formulas into well-formed formulas. Tautologies, by definition, are well-formed formulas. By what rule of inference do we transform into 'A→B→A' into '((A→B)→A)' or '(A→(B→A))'? I know of none. Additionally, there's more than one possibility, so any critic has the liberty of assuming the opposite one of what got intended. Or denying 'A→B→A' as a meaningful axiom altogether, because it is so ambiguous.
NO, those are NOT axioms a la Lukasiewicz.  His strings are well-formed.

@dougspoonwood And why would I care about that? If you’re a human, you know what I mean. That means you’re either a chump who won’t use his Prover9 to see what’s going on, or you can’t figure out whether or not it’s complete. If you’re a human in this world who knows anything about logic, you know exactly what those formulas are saying, and exactly why I didn’t include the brackets. What’s the rub anyway? Are you some sort of bracket police?

Why don’t you translate it like this, string freak: ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((A)))))))))))))))->(B->>>>>>>>>>>>>)A))))?

"If you’re a human, you know what I mean."  I don't know what you mean.  Again, 'A→B→A' is ambiguous.  I don't have Prover9 working on the computer I have now, and failed to get it working when I tried to.  Probably, because it's a different operating software.  Authors have BOTH used left association as an assumption and right association as an assumption.  The authors of Principia Mathematica also would assume A→B→A to either mean the left-association ((A→B)→A) OR ((A→B)^(B→A)).  But, I'm guessing you meant neither.  Also, Prover9 wouldn't prove any system incomplete. It doesn't make models.

I mean, Prover9 doesn't produce information from which we can find some assignment of values which works one for a subset of the well-formulas, but not for one of them, with some designated value.  Prover9 only deduces formulas.  There's a different program which works to find what we might call 'counterexamples'.

And again, I'm human.  Your conditional thus simply doesn't hold true.  If you're still not accepting a human person typing this, then you've engaged in dehumanization of a living, breathing person.

Ok? You are the one who dehumanized me first by acting like brackets are at all a reason to be a total condescending jerk.
It is just the case that you bracket right-associatively when dealing with long strings, and any encoding of hypothetical syllogism is a candidate for dropping brackets.
It’s like you’re from England, but driving on the left.
Also, my conditional holds because you know exactly what I meant.

Discussion about brackets is not a comment about you personally or you as a human being.  It concerns writing, which is external to you.  " It is just the case that you bracket right-associatively when dealing with long strings..." No, I don't do this.  When I write in Polish notation, I associate according to the connective symbols.  When people use parentheses they don't right-associate either.  They both concern long strings.  It doesn't matter what you meant or what others assume what you meant ... that is subjective, it matters what you wrote or will write, which is objective.

Ok? I wrote it to the people on this website, which means I’m writing it to people who already know bracket conventions, or who have the agency and decency to look into it for themselves. Instead, you decided to be a bracket Nazi, while also failing to actually address the question. You’re the epitome of what is wrong with formal methods in academia.

"I wrote it to the people on this website, which means I’m writing it to people who already know bracket conventions"  People who know such conventions realize that they differ among different authors.  As I tried to suggest, Russell and Whitehead would interpret 'A→B→A' as meaning ((A→B)→A) OR ((A→B)^(B→A)).  I've looked into this for myself.  A priori, it's all rubbish without well-formed formulas everywhere.  It's not rigorous to assume that your readers know or should know your convention as an author.  You do better to clarify or give some clue as to how to get clear.

"You’re the epitome of what is wrong with formal methods in academia."  And here you've further presumed a fair amount about me.  I don't think you're going to get far by presuming too much for your question in the above.  If do things more rigorously, you end up presuming less.  So that might help in resolving whatever question you have.

@DougSpoonwood your last comment is an inefficient way of saying nothing. I’ve presumed nothing that you haven’t proven for me.
